# Jenkinsfile: All stages not visible in Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the same Jenkinsfile on different branches of my GitRepo. But I am only able to see all the stages on the Jenkinsfile only on Master branch. On other branches, only a few of the Stages are visible.

The stages are not branch specific on the Jenkinsfile.

I have also seen similar behavior with other repositories as well. What am I missing in my branches or Jenkinsfile?

```
node {
stage('Checkout from Github') {
    checkout scm
}
try{

            stage('Unit Tests') {
                sh 'gradle test'
                junit 'build/test-results/test/*.xml'
            }
            stage('Integration Tests') {
                sh 'gradle integrationTest'
                junit 'build/test-results/integrationTest/*.xml'
            }
            stage('Coverage') {
                // generate test report
                sh 'gradle jacocoTestReport'
                // verify minimum coverage
                sh 'gradle jacocoTestCoverageVerification'
            }
            stage('SonarQube') {
                withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeServer') {
                    // submit results to SonarQube
                    sh 'gradle sonarqube'
                }
            }
            stage('Quality Gate') {
                timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                    // TODO: make this a failure criteria once coverage is ready
                    waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: false
                }
            }
            stage('Publish War') {
                sh 'gradle publish'
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Publish Helm Chart') {
        something
    }
} finally {
    something
}
}
```

[image: on feature branch]

[image: on master]

The Jenkinsfile is the same on both branches.

Comment: Obviously there is something more on the master branch config. Where is the "run container license" in this Jenkinsfile?

Comment: the jenkins file i copied and the screenshots that i made would have been from two different repos. but the images are from the same repo and they both have the same Jenkinsfile. The Jenkinsfile was added to show that i have a very basic Jenkinsfile nothing special for branches.

Comment: Please show then screenshots of how it fails for this Jenkinsfile that you showed us + the Jenkins config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipeline stage view plugin only displays stages that have been executed at least once by any build it displays.

In your screenshots you see exactly that. On master all stages have been executed in build #5, so they are represented by a column in the table. On the branch, there is only one build, which failed in an early stage, so there are only columns up to that stage, since the others have been skipped.

The behaviour can also be seen when you remove or –even more annoying– rename stages. The old stages keep having a column until they drop out of history.

Comment: Seems like that is the case. I was wondering because on all other repos the master and a feature branch showed similar behavior

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that both branches do not pull the required containers ...

the one does not seem to fetch at all - and the other seems to get a timeout.

the file which defines the container registry and/or containers might vary.